Is it Possible to Visualize the Graphical User Interface (GUI) of a Python Program Running on Pygame or PyQt using Google Project IDX?
I'm working on a Python project using either Pygame or PyQt to create a graphical user interface (GUI). However, I want to visualize this GUI through Google Project idx, which is a development environment for cloud-based coding and runing Python programs.
I have run into a few challenges:
1- Pygame GUI: When I run a Python script with Pygame, it creates a window locally. Is it possible to visualize this window remotely in Google Project IDX?
2- PyQt GUI: Similarly, for PyQt, the GUI also requires a local window to be shown. How can I view the graphical interface of a PyQt application remotely when running it through Google Project IDX?
3- Remote Display: Is there any way to set up a remote display or use any form of VNC or similar technology to show the graphical interface of a Python GUI when working in Google Project IDX?
I tried using remote display tools like vncserver, but ran into issues with package installation and permissions on my NixOS environment. I also explored the possibility of using x11vnc but had difficulties getting the display to show up on the browser.
Can anyone suggest the best approach to visualize a Python GUI (whether Pygame or PyQt) in the Google Project IDX environment? I am looking for a practical solution to this problem. Any help would be appreciated!
